# Electron Securty, how do I deny all permission requests

Tags: angular, security, electron

I am trying to secure my Angular/Electron app.

Therfore I am using electrongravity. It helped me to detect misconfiguration "forcing" me to set a `permissionCheckHandler`.

I have read the electron docs and came across this sentence:

```
To clear the handler, call `setPermissionCheckHandler(null)`.
```

Does this call automatically deny every permission request or only remove existing `permissionCheckHandler`?

Actually I am using it like this:

```
  win.webContents.session.setPermissionRequestHandler((webContents, permission, callback) => {
      return callback(false)
  });

  win.webContents.session.setPermissionCheckHandler((webContents, permission) => {
      return false
  });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is "electrongravity"?

Comment: Electronegativity is a tool to identify misconfigurations and security anti-patterns in Electron-based applications. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@doyensec/electronegativity

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deny every permission request you must configure it like:

```
  win.webContents.session.setPermissionRequestHandler((webContents, permission, callback) => {
      return callback(false)
  });

  win.webContents.session.setPermissionCheckHandler((webContents, permission) => {
      return false
  });
```